# Reach an element that created by random() in a list while creating the list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I know it's been a little confusing, but here is the question: I am creating a nested list comprehension, and I use random() to create the first 2 elements of inner list.I need to take a square of them and use them as 3. and 4. element of inner list.

```
[[random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10)] for n in range(100000)]
```

I know that this problem is easily solvable by using normal for loop but what i want is to solve it by using list comprehension, if possible. Expected output(or end) is like this:

```
[[random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10),index0**2,index1**2] for n in range(100000)]
```

Also, here is the current solution i am using:

```
full_list = []
for _ in range(100000):
  a = random.randint(0,10)
  b = random.randint(0,10)
  full_list.append([a,b,a**2,b**2])
```

Comment: Do you want to generate 4 numbers 100000 times?

Comment: yes, 2 numbers by randomly, and the other 2 numbers will be the square of the first 2 numbers.Index 0 : random Index 1: random Index 2: Square of index0 and Index 3: Square of index1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) in Python 3.8+:

```py
[[x := random.randint(0, 10), y := random.randint(0, 10), x**2, y**2] for _ in range(100000)]
```

Comment: I was thinking about walrus.. you did it ; good!